# Javascript variable inside another variable

Tags: javascript, variables

This is a var I create out of a cookie

```
var exiturl = readCookie("exiturl");
```

Here I have an exit popup script which normally must have a http://site.com
That script is writen as is:

```
var exitsplashpage = 'http://myexitpage.com' ;
```

I want to replace the `URL` by `my var exiturl`.

Thanks guys!

Comment: `var exitsplashpage = exiturl` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
var exitsplashpage = exiturl
```

Comment: not working get error

<script language="javascript">if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var script=document.createElement('script');script.src='jquery.min.js';script.type='text/javascript';head.appendChild(script);}var PreventExitSplash = false;var ESRecordId = '1';var exitpagerb = 2;var exitperiodrb = 0;var periodEnable = 0;var peroidDisable = 0;var displayFrequency = '';var ExitSplashLocation = '../exit/';var exitsplashpage = exiturl ;var exitsplashmessage ='*********';var UseAlert = 0;var UseAudio = 1;var UseHelper = 1;var AudioRB = '';</script>

Comment: From php it is working only if we refresh the page. This is why I want to use a JS cookie variable and insert it into that EXIT Script.

var exitsplashpage = '<?php echo $exiturl; ?>' ;

is what I have now but not efficient at all.